Price Data for a birdeye.so listed token is not showing up $JEFF
Apparently its a known glitch, but the price data for an established solana token is not showing up on Phantom. $JEFF
https://www.birdeye.so/token/A8LCx85weSxU4ubQS16twdSdYphbAEDdMd9GkZq5pump?chain=solana
